# Como filtrar objetos en Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Estoy haciendo una petición GET a la url API para encontrar un objeto que cumpla con el valor de la URL dado como parametro :

```
export async function getCursoByUrl(cursoUrl) {

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://cursos-89945-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/cursos.json?orderBy="url"&equalTo=${cursoUrl}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

En firebase los datos estan asi:
{
"c1": {
"url": "taller-de-fotografia-inicial",
"title": "fotografia",
},
"c2": {
"url": "ceramica-inicial",
"title": "ceramica",
},
"c3": {
"url": "fundamentos-de-lenceria",
"title": "lenceria",
}
}

Entonces quiero traer los datos que coincidan con el valor de la url dada
Y obtengo un error desde el componente que usa ese valor:

```
error: "Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive"
```

Comment: El par de llaves que rodea a los objetos deben ser corchetes, indicando que es un array de objetos

Comment: Pero en firebase estan bien los datos y me tira ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que viene en el parametro cursoURL es como deberia de esperarse un string, pero por la forma en la que esta diseñada la api de firebase se lo debes proporcionar entrecomillado, solo agrega las comillas a tu literal asi:

```js
async function getCursoByUrl(cursoUrl) {

    const response = await fetch(
     `https://cursos-89945-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/cursos.json?orderBy="url"&equalTo="${cursoUrl}"`
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
    return data;
   }
   
   getCursoByUrl("taller-de-fotografia-inicial");
```